# openFileOutput() , opernFileInput() equivalent in iOS (Porting Android app to iOS platform)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a beginner in iOS development. But I have some knowledge in Android development. I have developed several apps on the Android platform. So since I'm learning iOS development I thought it would be nice to port my applications to the iOS platform then it will be a great learning experience.

I started one of my projects which uses TCP socket programming to send seekbar values to an Esp8266-12E. In that app I use `openFileOutput()` and `openFileInput()` methods to save the last sent values in private files.

Now my question is: how to achieve the same result on the iOS platform? Those files should not be accessible to the user. Because if they are and the user changes the values in that file ESP8266, my app would be out of sync.

Comment: Though the names tell a couple of information, what do you expect from those two functions?

Comment: openFileOutput(String name, int mode)
Open a private file for writing. This means user of the application cannot access it using a file browser. Only my code can access it. and read values from it.   [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int))

Comment: openFileInput(String name)
Open a private file for reading. In this my app can access the file for writing data. But user cannot. It's private only my app can see it.. User cannot and user can't change values by opening it in a text editor.[link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileInput(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of saving the values in files, you could use [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata) to save and access the variables between runs.

Comment: I didn't fully understood what you are telling. Since i am very beginner and self learning i have very less knowledge about core data... Can you explain? What i am going to achieve by openFileOutput() or input is to save the values and then later time... maybe 1 week later load those last saved values again and use them..   So using Core Data can i do that? Save some values and use them after a week again?     Researched a bit more. Found a tutorial stating that Coredata will survive a reboot and the data is persistance. Yeah. This will work.